# Is it possible to schedule an R script to run on machine image (EC2) within R?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm using a version of R studio hosted on an Amazon EC2 server. Is it possible to SCHEDULE R execute a script that downloads data from various APIs, cleans it, then downloads it to a remote server (Amazon RDS)?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: If you can use EC2, presumably you can use cron?

Comment: Yes, I will look from here. Thanks.